# Dynamic generated content won't wrap arround floated image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

When I generate content it will not wrap arround the image, if I make it static it will wrap

(static)

```
 | Image | text text
 | ..... | text text
 | ..... | text text
 | text  | text text
```

(dynamic)

```
 | Image |          |
 | ..... |          |
 | ..... |          |
 | text  | text text|
 | text  | text text|


 <div class="somediv">
  <div class="floatbox">
    <%= image_tag 'thumb_1.jpg' %>
  </div>
  <p>
    <%= @posts.first.content %>
  </p>
</div>


 .somediv{
   width: 350px;
   clear: left;
   border: 1px solid gray;
 }

.somediv .floatbox{
  float: left;
}
```

howcome this is the beaviour, and how do I overcome it.

Comment: The answare to this stupid question is that the generated content were just one long string, which I guess was interpeted as one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answare to this stupid question is that the generated content were just one long string, which I guess was interpeted as one word, and caused it to overflow.